# Javascript variable not updating value

Tags: javascript

This is makinkg me crazy, i cant Get the outside variable Get the inside data

Sorry for the bad formating I'm writing from the phone, if someone can helpme out with the format I appreciate it

```
  window.getReasons = function(line) {
    var $reasons;

    $reasons = "";
    $.get(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + "allLineReasons.js?line=" + line, function(returnData) {
      $reasons = returnData.toString();
      return console.log("T_T ----->" + returnData.toString());
    }, "html");
    console.log($reasons);
    return $reasons;
  };
```

Comment: I don;t know what you mean by the "outside variable" and "inside data"  Can you be specific about what you are trying to do?

Comment: @EH_warch, look at jbabey's link. $.get is asynchronous, you should never get the correct value to return in getReasons()

Comment: this will not work, because you are returning the reason variable before it is set to its new value. Remember that this is an asynchronous call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important thing for you to understand is that `$.get()` is ASYNCHRONOUS by default.  So what is happening is that your `console.log()` and `return` statements that follow your call to `get()` are executing before the `get()` has returned it's value.

You might look to utilize the `when()` method here to handle the deferred object that is returned from `get()`

```
window.getReasons = function(line) {
    var reasons = '';
    $.when(
        $.get(window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + "allLineReasons.js?line=" + line)
    ).done(function(jqxhr) {
        data = jqxhr[0];   
        reasons = data.toString();
    });
    console.log(reasons);
    return reasons;
}
```

Comment: I did not know about the when function, and did not thought of done. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do this in core javascript?

Answer (score 1):

$reasons won't be updated until after the GET completes on the server and the response is returned. But your console.log will execute immediately after the request is made.